# Rails: Form Routes to Wrong View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form submitting to a custom action, 'add_participants', on the 'order_items' controller. It appears to submit to the correct action, but **the error references an unrelated view**, the view associated with 'order_items#new'.

**What I have tried** includes:

- Changing the route description from 'add_participants' to '/add_participants', and vice versa.
- Creating a specific 'add_participants.html.erb' file in the 'order_items' folder.
- Changing from <%= form_for @new_oi ... %> to <%= form_for OrderItem.new ... %> in various incarnations

**The Error**

```
ArgumentError in OrderItems#add_participants

Showing /path/to/app/views/order_items/new.html.erb where line #7 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Extracted source (around line #7):

<%= form_for @order_item do |f| %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.hidden_field :company_id, :value => '2' %>

app/views/order_items/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_order_items_new_html_erb__1443667659032443898_70275798467060'
app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in add_participants'
app/controllers/order_items_controller.rb:71:in `add_participants'
```

**The Route**

```
post '/add_participants', to: 'order_items#add_participants'
```

**The Submitting Form**

```
<%= form_for @new_oi, :url => {:action => "add_participants"}, method: :post, :html => { :id => "add_participants", :class => "add_participants" } do |f| %>
```

**Controller Action**

```
*line 71*       def add_participants
        @original_oi = OrderItem.find_by_id(session[:current_order_item_id].to_i)
        @order = @original_oi.order
        @new_oi = OrderItem.new(order_item_params)

        respond_to do |format|
            if @new_oi.save
                format.html { redirect_to change_confirmation_path }
                format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @new_oi }
            else
*line 78*           format.html { render action: 'new', notice: "We're sorry, but we were unable to complete this purchase." }
                format.json { render json: @new_oi.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end
    end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just needed to study the error location more closely. The record wasn't saving, so the add_participants action was attempting to render the new view.

Comment: And you just changed the url either in controller or `form_for`?

Comment: I changed the render action in line 78 of the controller.